# How can I prevent regular users from connecting to new wireless networks?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have a created a wireless connection from the main admin account and checked the box saying "Available to all users", everything is working correctly. How can I prevent the desktop users from switching to a different wireless connection?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's an easier way than this, but the first thing that comes to mind is to configure a static IP on the wireless interface.  Make it something weird.

Answer (score 0):

1. make a program that takes no arguments and connect to the internet with suid set (it can be a simple program just executing the shell command using system();)
2. disable their use of iwconfig/other wireless tools/etc whatsoever
3. allow them to run the suid program

doesn't sound very secure to me but probably does the job...